# Is a splash screen necessary for an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, splash-screen

It is the first time I am going to sumbmit my app. I know from a document that launch images should be specified, but I have created my own launch view (a viewcontroller with a uilabel and a uiimageview) and it work great . But if I do not make launch images, I am afraid of not being accepted. Can someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote by Apple:

> Custom icons and images:
>   - Application icon (required for all apps)
>   - App icon for the App Store (required for all apps)
>   - Launch image (required for all apps)
>   - [...]

The app will indeed be rejected when no launch image is specified.
Simply take a screenshot of your custom launch viewer, that's all :)

Comment: If I take a screenshot of my custom launch viewer, there will be duplicated launch view. So can I just specify a total black image?

Comment: The launch image is only shown during the launch of an application (generally just milliseconds). In other words, the launch image is only visible from the moment the user clicks the icon until the moment the first window becomes visible. This way users feel like the application launched quickly, while in fact the image was shown first and disappeared as soon the application actually launched. Make sure the launch image is equal to the launch view, this way the user won't notice the transition. The launch image is not intended to show credits, it just improves user experience.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It is required. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html [image]

Also it is the most easy task in the world. You just need to set an image as splash/launch image.

UPDATED : From Apple HIG : `Design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the app. The launch image gives users the impression that your app is fast and responsive because it appears instantly and is quickly replaced by the first screen of your app.`

**Updated link:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1

Comment: Can I just specify a total black image?

Comment: Sorry for this much late reply. You can specify a black image but its not ideal, see updated answer.

Comment: @itenyh, why wouldn't you want to have your company logo displayed? Remind the users who created the app.

Answer (score 2):

To submit your app to the app store, you **need a launch image**. You don't need to build it in Interface Builder or programatically, it's just a picture. You can do this quickly and easily by running the iPhone Simulator and taking a screenshot. Then all you have to do is copy the image into your target folder and specify that image to be used as a launch image:

[image]

Just drag your image file into the box.

Here is the apple documentation on image requirements for applications: [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Answer (score -5):

No, it is not required to set a launch image.

Comment: Launch image is necessary for IOS application. Check the documentation

Comment: may be, but your app will not be rejected if a launch image is not set

Comment: @Chakalaka: Even if it's just a black image, a launch screen is required.  You ***will*** be rejected.

Comment: It is required for iPhone 5(a black image will do), but it is NOT required for other iDevices.

Comment: I have had two apps approved (in the last two months) that did not have launch images specified.  I know that this contradicts the documentation, but that's my experience.  I will also note that the validation process does NOT check for a launch image.

Comment: @software; yes. In the early days Apple said 'no launch screens' (my enterprise company freaked out and took theirs out) - even though most apps (I showed the director that over 70% of the apps on my iPhone had them) - I always have had one on my startup company's apps. Apple has policies that try to 'shape' the look and feel of apps - but they aren't pass/fail tests.