# Splash spinner not showing in PhoneGap 2.4

Tags: ios, cordova

For some reason my splash spinner is not working in my PhoneGap 2.4 app for iOS but I have

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

Are there any basic troubleshooting tips to try and get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but in PhoneGap 2.5. I just migrated from 2.4 where the spinner used to show up on both: iPad and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Do you the correct image specifications for splashs creens? Can you see them in XCode project summary ? Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117556/is-a-splash-screen-necessary-for-an-iphone-app) and [this](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/) .

Comment: Yes my splash screens are the correct size and format for all devices.

Comment: So when you run the app what do you see?

Comment: The splash screen shows up and app loads properly, just does not show the spinner when the app inits.