# Why is a Launch Image needed despite having a Lauch Screen File?

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9, launchimage

In iOS 10 I used a `Launch Screen File` instead of `Launch Images`:

[image]

After converting to Swift 4 in Xcode 9 for iOS 11 I get the following warning:

> Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image

[image]

Why is a launch image needed when there is already the launch screen?

Comment: Your answer can be found in the link below [Your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117556/is-a-splash-screen-necessary-for-an-iphone-app)

Comment: @MonwellPartee Launch Images are not required when there are Launch Screens. It seems to be a bug in Xcode, see my answer below.

Comment: I agree, seems to be a bug since Launch Images are now deprecated but still shows up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to temporarily add a launch image asset catalog.

1. Click on `Use Asset Catalog...`:

[image]

2. Choose to create a new asset catalog:

[image]

3. Switch back to `Don't use asset catalogs`:

[image]

4. Delete the automatically created `Images.xcassets`.
5. The warning is gone.

Comment: Do you know what difference this makes to the xcodeproj?

Comment: @Simon It apparently clears our artifacts. Which exactly I don't know as I cannot reproduce the bug to get those artifacts. However, the procedure in the solution seems to be safe. No problems since then.

Comment: This doesnt work with Xcode 11 / iOS 13 because the launch images source is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9.4, if we click on `iOS 8.0 and later`, `LaunchImage` will show up a slot called `iPhone X Portrait iOS 11+`

[image]

You need to refer to Static Launch Screen Images guide https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/. Here is the sizes for iPhone X

```
iPhone X    portrai 1125px × 2436px landscape 2436px × 1125px
```

[image]

Comment: The question title did not fully reflect the question content, so I updated it. The question is: why is a Launch Image needed *despite already having a Lauch Screen File*? As you see in my answer, it was due to a bug in Xcode that messed up the project settings.